# How to sum string items in list box

Tags: c#

How can I sum items in Listbox if the items string not integer?

```
listBox1.Items.Add("merry has (5 $) ")
listBox1.Items.Add("sandy has (10 $)")
```

I need to add this dollars and the output will be in label.

Comment: is the output consistent? meaning, are the integers always between the first `(` and the first `$`?

Comment: This is why you should data bind...

Answer (score 3):

```
var sum = listBox1.Items.Cast<string>()
                  .Select(x => int.Parse(Regex.Match(x, @"\d+").Value))
                  .Sum();
```

in case, some of your items don't contain any numbers

```
var sum = listBox1.Items.Cast<string>()
                  .Select(x => Regex.Match(x, @"\d+").Value)
                  .Where(x=> !String.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
                  .Select(x=>int.Parse(x))
                  .Sum();
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312(v=vs.110).aspx), they will help you extract the numbers from the strings.

Then have a look at [Int32.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert them to numbers.

And finally have a look at [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386928(v=vs.110).aspx) to learn how to sum them up.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it, but not nearly as concise as EZI's solution:

```
int sum = 0;

foreach (var item in listBox1.Items.Cast<string>())
{
    int tmp;
    int startInt = item.IndexOf('(');
    int endInt = item.IndexOf('$');

    if (startInt > -1 &&
        endInt > startInt &&
        int.TryParse(item.Substring(++startInt, endInt - startInt), out tmp))
    {
        sum += tmp;
    }
}

MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Sum is: {0} $", sum));

// Output:
// Sum is: 15 $
```

Comment: it gives me red line under IndexOf and  Substring                               'object' does not contain a definition for 'IndexOf' and no extension method 'IndexOf' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @nana Oh, sorry! Forgot to cast Items to a list of strings. I've updated the code above (added `.Cast<string>()` to `Items` in the `foreach`)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach without regex using a custom `NumberFormatInfo` for `decimal.TryParse`:

```
NumberFormatInfo nfi = new NumberFormatInfo();
nfi.CurrencySymbol = "$";
nfi.CurrencyPositivePattern = 3;
nfi.CurrencyNegativePattern = 8;
nfi.NegativeSign = "-";
decimal value = 0;
var dollars = from item in listBox1.Items.Cast<string>()
              let startIndex = item.IndexOf("(")
              where startIndex >= 0
              let endIndex = item.IndexOf(")", startIndex + 1)
              where endIndex >= 0
              let parsable = decimal.TryParse(item.Substring(startIndex + 1, endIndex - startIndex - 1), NumberStyles.Currency, nfi, out value)
              where parsable
              select value;
decimal sumDollars = dollars.Sum();
```

The [positive patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencypositivepattern(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
0  $n 
1  n$
2  $ n
3  n $
```

The [negative patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencynegativepattern(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

To build on DavidP's idea, you could use a custom class to store both the display string and dollar value.

For example, consider this simple class that takes your string as a parameter to the constructor, and has two properties: DisplayText (string) and DollarValue (int) (and it overrides the ToString() method for display in a ListBox). It automatically grabs the dollar amount from your string and sets its `DollarValue` property accordingly:

```
private class CustomListItem
{
    public string DisplayText { get; private set; }
    public int DollarValue { get; private set; }

    public CustomListItem(string text)
    {
        this.DisplayText = text;
        this.DollarValue = GetDollarValueFromString(text);
    }

    private int GetDollarValueFromString(string input)
    {
        if (input == null) return 0;

        int dollarValue = 0;
        int start = input.IndexOf('(');
        int end = input.IndexOf('$');

        if (start > -1 && end > start)
        {
            int.TryParse(
                input.Substring(++start, end - start), 
                out dollarValue);
        }

        return dollarValue;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return DisplayText;
    }
}
```

You could create a list of these classes based on the strings from your datasource and add them to your ListBox, something like:

```
// Normally items would come from some external datasource
var items = new List<string>
{
    "merry has (5 $)",
    "sandy has (10 $)"
};

// Add our CustomListItem class instead of strings to the list box
items.ForEach(i => listBox1.Items.Add(new CustomListItem(i)));
```

Now, when you want to display the sum, you can just use the `.DollarValue` property of your custom class:

```
int sum = listBox1.Items.Cast<CustomListItem>().Sum(item => item.DollarValue);
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Sum is: {0} $", sum));
```

Answer (score -3):

I would add the dollar amount as the value of the Listbox Item, and the whole bit of text as the text.

```
ListItem li1 = new ListItem();
li1.Text = "merry has (5 $)";
li1.Value = "5";
listBox1.Items.Add(li1);

ListItem li2 = new ListItem();
li2.Text = "sandy has (10 $)"
li2.Value = "10";
listBox1.Items.Add(li2);
```

You can then add them together pretty easy:

```
double sumMoney = 0;
foreach (ListItem li in listBox1.Items)
{
     sumMoney = sumMoney + Convert.ToDouble(li.Value);
}
lblText.Text = sumMoney.ToString()
```

Comment: Suppose OP reads that string `sandy has (10 $)` from a file or form a DB at runtime...

Comment: Not sure why my answer deserves a (-1)? Obviously if you read the whole string from a file or db you would need to pick apart that string using RegEx or string functions to get at the number portion.

Comment: Picking apart the string is really the basis of his question. Your answer does not answer that at all. Although I do agree it would be better to store the value somewhere so you're only picking apart the string once, rather than on each calculation. But that is a secondary design-related question.

Comment: I posted an answer based on the spirit of your suggestion

Comment: You hardcode the values in your answer. Suppose you get `"merry has (5 $)"` from *db/file/user-input* and don't know the value `5` at compile time.

Comment: I would argue that the basis of his question is not string manipulation per say, but how to add up dollar values imbedded in a string. However, I am not going to waste anymore time arguing.